# Setup Nginx as a proxy that adds a specific header to any responses

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm putting together a few Docker containers to allow my team to spot XSS vulnerabilities in their apps by launching a Google Chrome instance using a particular proxy server. e.g.,

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp --proxy-server=http://localhost:8080
```

Then they can navigate to any URLs, do some testing and check the results.

On port 8080 is an Nginx server which I use as a proxy to add a specific header to *any* responses:

```
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: require-trusted-types-for 'script'; report-uri //localhost:9090
```

What this header will do is to report any CSP violations to `localhost:9090` which runs a CSP report collector service.

The only thing that Nginx has to do is:

1. Let any request through
2. Intercept any response and add the header
3. Let the response through

Here's my current Nginx conf:

*As you can see below I haven't made any attempt to add the header yet (that's fine I'll manage this later), however I'm really struggling with point 3. I can see requests going through Nginx but nothing seems to come out of it.*

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
      proxy_pass $host;
    }
  }
}
```

How do I configure Nginx to do that? I'm also open to alternatives to Nginx if that's simpler.

---

For example when I navigate to bbc.co.uk

I can see this in Nginx logs:

```
proxy_1          | 172.18.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2020:15:04:01 +0000] "CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 400 173 "-" "-"
proxy_1          | 172.18.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2020:15:04:01 +0000] "CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 400 173 "-" "-"
proxy_1          | 172.18.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2020:15:04:01 +0000] "CONNECT bbc.co.uk:443 HTTP/1.1" 400 173 "-" "-"
proxy_1          | 172.18.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2020:15:04:01 +0000] "CONNECT bbc.co.uk:443 HTTP/1.1" 400 173 "-" "-"
proxy_1          | 172.18.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2020:15:04:02 +0000] "CONNECT bbc.co.uk:443 HTTP/1.1" 400 173 "-" "-"
proxy_1          | 172.18.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2020:15:04:02 +0000] "CONNECT bbc.co.uk:443 HTTP/1.1" 400 173 "-" "-"
```

And Chrome says the website cannot be reached.

Comment: Oops, I missed that on first read as I didn't side-scroll your command line. Interesting. nginx wasn't really intended to act as a forward proxy. But this ought to give you at least some sort of response from the origin server. Check the nginx container logs to see if anything potentially useful is in there.

Comment: OK, CONNECT is definitely not supported in nginx at all. You'll need to use a proper forward proxy server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ok thanks, that's already helpful :-) Any suggestions as to how I could approach this? Ideally I'd love to see a response from you but I'll take anything really.

Comment: Forget the proxy server and serve the header with the actual app (or rather, the dev version of the app).

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's fair enough. Thx.